# Perl & MongoDB binary data

Tags: perl, mongodb

From the [MongoDB](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB::DataTypes) manual:

> By default, all database strings are UTF8. To save images, binaries,
> and other non-UTF8 data, you can pass the string as a reference to the
> database.

I'm fetching pages and want store the content for later processing.

- I can not rely on meta-charset, because many pages has utf8 content but wrongly declaring  iso-8859-1 or similar
- so can't use `Encode` (don't know the originating charset)
- therefore, I want store the content simply `as flow of bytes` (binary data) for later processing

Fragment of my code:

```
sub save {
    my ($self, $ok, $url, $fetchtime, $request ) = @_;

    my $rawhead = $request->headers_as_string;
    my $rawbody = $request->content;

    $self->db->content->insert(
        { "url" => $url, "rhead" => \$rawhead, "rbody" => \$rawbody } ) #using references here
      if $ok;

    $self->db->links->update(
        { "url" => $url },
        {
            '$set' => {
                'status'       => $request->code,
                'valid'        => $ok,
                'last_checked' => time(),
                'fetchtime'    => $fetchtime,
            }
        }
    );
}
```

But get error:

> Wide character in subroutine entry at
> /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/darwin-multi-2level/MongoDB/Collection.pm
> line 296.

This is the only place where I storing data.

The question: The only way store binary data in MondoDB is encode them e.g. with base64?

Comment: Will it give the same warning if you set `$rawhead` and `$rawbody` to the sample given in the manual (i.e., `"\xFF\xFE\xFF"`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like another sad story about `_utf8_` flag...

I may be wrong, but it seems that `headers_as_string` and `content` methods of HTTP::Message return their strings as a sequence of characters. But MongoDB driver expects the strings explicitly passed to it as 'binaries' to be a sequence of octets - hence the warning drama.

A rather ugly fix is to take down the `utf8` flag on $rawhead and $rawbody in your code (I wonder shouldn't it be really done by MongoDB driver itself?), by something like this...

```
_utf8_off $rawhead; 
_utf8_off $rawbody; # ugh
```

The alternative is to use `encode('utf8', $rawhead)` - but then you should use `decode` when extracting values from DB, and I doubt it's not uglier.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is characters, not octets. Your assumption seems to be that you are just passing things through as octets, but you must have violated that assumption earlier somehow by decoding incoming text data, perhaps even without you noticing.

So simply do not decode, data stay octets, storing into the db won't fail.